# convert serialport.readline() non-ascii string into a byte array

Tags: c#, string, encoding, serial-port

I want to use **serialport.readline()** because it's a blocking call and the data I'm getting has 0x0D 0x0A (CR LF) at the end. However, what I want is an Hex String instead of an Ascii representation.

For example, the device I am communication with is sending byte arrays like {0xff,0xff,0x45,0x0D,0x0A}. I want to simply print out in my program just like this: 0xff, 0xff,0x45.  Readline() kindly trims out LF and CR.

I though about using **serialport.read(buff[]...)** by specifying how many bytes I want to read. But it didn't work very well because if I am reading too fast half of the array will be 0x00 and if I am reading too slow, there will be an overflow for the com port. I don't want to lose any bytes.

I tried to convert what I got from **serialport.readline()** to a byte array but the hex string I got usually turns into **0x3f**. Code is like this:

```
var line = string.Join(",", mySerialPort.ReadLine().Select(c => ((Byte)c).ToString("X")).ToArray());
```

I changed the encoding a few times (ASCII, UTF8,UNICODE) but still no go.

Is there any way to convert the **non-Ascii** String I got from **readline()** into a byte array?

Comment: @leppie you mean Encoding.ACSII.getBytes(String)? it gives me the same results. Hex numbers turn into 0x3F all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you shouldn't be reading it as *text* data at all.

You're fundamentally dealing with binary data, so use the overload of [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549.aspx) which takes a *byte* array rather than a *char* array. (Or call `ReadByte` repeatedly.)

Any time you try to treat arbitrary binary data as if it's text, you're going to have a bad experience.

It sounds like you've already tried this, but done it badly:

> But it didn't work very well because if I am reading too fast half of the array will be 0x00

That suggests you're ignoring the return value of `Read`, which says how many bytes have actually been read. You should have something like:

```
int bytesRead = port.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
// Now use the portion of buffer which is from 0 (inclusive) to
// bytesRead (exclusive).
```

Comment: you are right. I tried it before but I have to limit the speed I am reading to avoid overflow or "over read". By saying "over read" I mean the read() method empties buffer too fast so it returns 0x00

Comment: @Timtianyang: See the second half of my post - it's fine to read with a buffer that's too large, so long as you take account of the return value from `Read`.

Comment: So is it like bytesRead=port.Read(buff,bytesRead,buffer.length);  so the next time it will put new bytes into buffer with offset=bytesRead ?

Comment: @Timtianyang: If you haven't actually *used* those bytes yet, yes - but `buffer.Length - bytesRead` for the count (otherwise the arguments are invalid).

Comment: Thank you Sir. It effectively avoids "over read" and I can read as fast as I can to avoid overflow. You made my day.

Comment: @Timtianyang: One thing to bear in mind - this is how you should read from *all* streams - network, file, memory, serial ports etc.